# Tracing a recursive evaluator

Tags: lua, lisp, interpreter, trace, evaluation

I wrote a simple Lisp interpreter in *Moonscript Lua*. The *evaluator* looks like this:

```
eval = ( env, expr ) ->
    if is_symbol expr
        lookup env, expr
    elseif is_define expr 
        eval_define env, expr
    elseif is_lambda expr 
        eval_lambda env, expr
    else call (map (partial eval, env), expr)
```

It works fine. 
But now I would really like to trace out the process, in a way that looks something like this:

```
(+ (+ a b) (+ a c))

(+ (+ 1 2) (+ 1 4))

(+ 3 5)

8
```

The thing is, since the evaluation process is recursive, at no point do I have the whole expression to print out.

Do I have to rewrite the evaluator in imperative style or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you want the trace to look as if something different is happening than actually is happening then you probably need to write an evaluator that does that something different, yes.  Personally, I'd want the trace to display what the evaluator actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is using Common Lisp, because I don't really know Lua.

### Actual trace

Typically, you want to trace what actually happens in your code. 
Here is a rewrite of your function and an example of what a tracing tool can do:

```lisp
(defun normal-eval (form env)
  (etypecase form
    (cons (destructuring-bind (op . args) form
            (apply op
                   (mapcar (lambda (u)
                             (normal-eval u env))
                           args))))
    (null nil)
    (symbol (cdr (assoc form env)))
    (t form)))

> (trace normal-eval)
> (normal-eval '(+ (+ 1 3 a) 2) '((a . 5)))

0: (NORMAL-EVAL (+ (+ 1 3 A) 2) ((A . 5)))
  1: (NORMAL-EVAL (+ 1 3 A) ((A . 5)))
    2: (NORMAL-EVAL 1 ((A . 5)))
    2: NORMAL-EVAL returned 1
    2: (NORMAL-EVAL 3 ((A . 5)))
    2: NORMAL-EVAL returned 3
    2: (NORMAL-EVAL A ((A . 5)))
    2: NORMAL-EVAL returned 5
  1: NORMAL-EVAL returned 9
  1: (NORMAL-EVAL 2 ((A . 5)))
  1: NORMAL-EVAL returned 2
0: NORMAL-EVAL returned 11
```

### Desired trace

There is no easy way as far as I know to have the kind of output you want with the code you provided.
But if you are willing to change your code, you can obtain the trace you want in a purely functional fashion, simply by rewriting the term step-by-step. However, you have to prevent evaluating a term that was already evaluated, in order to let the form be gradually changed.

```lisp
(defun s-eval (x env)
  (etypecase x
    (cons (destructuring-bind (new-list . some-evalp)
              (reduce
               (lambda (element R)
                 (destructuring-bind (rec-list . some-evalp) R
                   (multiple-value-bind (value evalp) (s-eval element env)
                     (cons (list* value rec-list)
                           (or some-evalp evalp)))))
               (rest x)
               :from-end t
               :initial-value (cons nil nil))
            (values
             (if some-evalp
                 ;; a least one element required some work
                 ;; so we return the modified term. 
                 (cons (first x) new-list)
                 ;; all elements are literal, we can actually
                 ;; replace this form by its evaluation
                 (apply (first x) new-list))
             T)))
    (null (values nil nil))
    (symbol (values (cdr (assoc x env)) t))
    (t (values x nil))))

(defun step-eval (form &optional env)
  (print form)
  (multiple-value-bind (value evalp)
      (s-eval form env)
    (if evalp
        (step-eval value env)
        value)))

> (step-eval '(+ (+ 1 3 a) 2) '((a . 5)))


(+ (+ 1 3 A) 2) 
(+ (+ 1 3 5) 2) 
(+ 9 2) 
11


> (step-eval '(+ (+ 1 3 a) (* b a)) '((a . 5) (b . 0)))


(+ (+ 1 3 A) (* B A)) 
(+ (+ 1 3 5) (* 0 5)) 
(+ 9 0) 
9

> (step-eval '(+ (+ a b) (+ a c)) '((a . 1)
                                  (b . 2)
                                  (c . 4)))


(+ (+ A B) (+ A C)) 
(+ (+ 1 2) (+ 1 4)) 
(+ 3 5) 
8
```

`S-EVAL` evaluates a form in an environment and returns two values: the evaluation of the form and a boolean indicating whether some evaluation *actually* occurred or if the term was self-evaluating (a literal). This boolean is used to prevent transforming a term where a subterm was transformed by a recursive evaluation.
`STEP-EVAL` prints the form and calls `S-EVAL`, before calling itself recursively until evaluation terminates.

Comment: Very nice! In hindsight I can see how what I was asking didn't really make sense. I'll play around with your s-eval and see if I can rewrite it in Lua.

Comment: I understand that S-eval returns as second value nil or T based on if the form is self-evaluating or not, in order to stop the process.
Would it also work to test if the form is equal before and after evaluation at every step, or would that hit some edge cases I am not seeing?

Comment: @yawn I don't see any edge case either, I think it could work like that too.